# nodemailer doesn't stop sending mails

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I have a simple nodemailer setup that sends emails without a problem. The only thing I can't figure out is how to stop it from sending once it started. I click send, it sends an email but the page keeps loading and soon I receive another email etc. Surely it should only send one email and close the process.

Can anybody see something I'm doing wrong here?

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
    host: 'mail.francotanzarella.com',
    secureConnection: false,
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'contact@francotanzarella.com',
        pass: '***'
    }
});

app.post('/contact', function(req, res) {
var htmlTpl = '<h4>Message from' + ' ' + req.body.name + '</h4><p><span>' + req.body.email + '</span</p><p>' + req.body.message + '</p>'; 
    mailOptions = {
        from: 'noreply@francotanzarella.com',
        to: 'contact@francotanzarella.com',
        subject: 'New message from francotanzarella.com',
        html: htmlTpl,
        debug: true
    }
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            console.log(response.message);
        }
        smtpTransport.close();
    });
});
```

contact.ejs

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" name="userForm" action="/contact" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 column">

                <div class="row" ng-class="{ 'error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine && submitted }">
                    <div class="small-12 column">
                        <label for="name" class="inline">Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 column">
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="name" required />
                        <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine">Please enter your name</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row" ng-class="{ 'error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine && submitted }">
                    <div class="small-12 column">
                        <label for="email" class="inline">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 column">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" ng-model="email" required />
                        <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine">I need a valid email please</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row" ng-class="{ 'error' : userForm.message.$invalid && !userForm.message.$pristine && submitted }">
                    <div class="small-12 column">
                        <label for="message" class="inline">Message</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 column">
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Send me a message" ng-model="message" required></textarea>
                        <small class="error" ng-show="userForm.message.$invalid && !userForm.message.$pristine">What? No message?</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 column">
                        <button type="submit" class="button" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form-response-container">
            <div id="for-response-inner">
                <h3 id="form-response"></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Every time you POST to `/contact` an email is sent. Did you verify if it is node-mailer that sends multiple emails or are you just POSTing multiple times?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can test if it's node-mailer or me that is posting multiple times. I added my contact.ejs, hopefully there is a hint of what I am doing wrong in there but it's pretty standard stuff.

Comment: check it with chrome dev tools, on the network tab you can track the network activity of your app.

Comment: Use `console.log()` in the function handler for the POST request. Then, see the console to identify if it is node-mailer or multiple POST requests.

Comment: When I check chrome's dev tool it only says (pending) until I receive 2 emails then it times out. what should I log with console.log()? I tried smtpTransport and app.post but I don't see anything useful there. Sorry if this is obvious but I'm learning as I'm going.

Answer (score 6):

Okay I fixed this. Not sure if it's the correct method but it works. I basically pass the browser a ok (200) when the email was sent successfully.

```
if(error) {
    res.send(500);
} else {
    res.send(200);
}
```

Comment: `.send()` is now deprecated. Use `.sendStatus()` instead.

Comment: `.sendStatus()` is now used in Express, but not in out-of-the-box node. What worked for me was `response.statusCode = <500 or 200 here>` as well as `res.end()` in both the `if` and the `else`. There's probably a more elegant resolution for this, but I don't know it unfortunately.